# Passar por um método em todas as rotas de todos métodos http exceto duas

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js, rotas

Basicamente eu quero fazer com que todas as rotas que venham de qualquer método http (get, post, put, ...) passem, primeiro, por um método que fará a verificação se o usuário esta autenticado, porém, esse método não deve ser chamado quando o usuário irá se autenticar (método `POST` rota `/auth`) e quando ele irá se cadastrar (método `POST` rota `/user`). Lembrando que possuo outros métodos na rota `/user` e outras rotas com o método `POST`

Gostaria de uma solução que não envolvesse chamar uma função em todos os lugares necessários, tem como fazer algo como `router.all()` ou `router.use()` num único lugar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Middlewares](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html). Basta declarar um antes das suas rotas, e definir nele a lógica para permitir ou recusar o request:

```
var app = express()

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    // endpoints ignorados
    if ((req.url === '/auth' || req.url === '/user') && req.method === 'POST') {
        // `next()` significa "ok, pode continuar na rota `req.url`"
        next();
    }
    // checa login
    else if (/*checa se usuário está logado*/) {
        next();
    }
    // não logado, envia erro ou whatever vc quiser.
    else {
        res.status(401).send('Você precisa logar');
    }
});

// ... suas rotas GET, POST, etc
```

Comment: Nesse caso o status é 401 (não autenticado), 403 é quando o usuário está autenticado porém não possui permissão

Comment: Verdade, confusão minha. Fixed na resposta.