# Erro ao escapar uma url em express js de um middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, express.js, jwt

Estou com um problema para escapar uma **Url** da validação de **Token**. Estou usando a lib **jwt** ***(jsonwebtoken)*** para restringir os acessos a request de minha api, porém quero deixa a url `/imagem/:parametro` sem a validação por token. Pois hoje quando faço o seguinte request `/imagem/teste.png` ele não deixa passar sem o token.

Estou fazendo da seguinte maneira:

***Meu server.js***

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const consign = require('consign');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const fileupload = require('express-fileupload');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

module.exports = function(){

    //define a url para arquivos estáticos
    app.use('/public', express.static('./app/public'));
    //habilta request e response json
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    //habilita o middleware de upload
    app.use(fileupload());

    //verifica se o token é valido
    app.use(function(request, response, next){

        if(request.originalUrl == '/token' || request.originalUrl == '/login' || request.originalUrl == '/imagem/' ){
            return next();
        }else{


            if (request.headers.authorization && request.headers.authorization.split(' ')[0] === 'Bearer') {

                var token = request.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];

                jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_KEY, function(err, decoded) {
                    if (err) return response.status(500).send({ auth: false, message: 'Falha ao autenticar o token.' });

                    request.userId = decoded.id;
                    next();
                });


            } else if (request.query && request.query.token) {
                next();
                return request.query.token;
            }else{
                response.json("Não Autorizado!");
                next();
            }

        }

    });




    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
      next();
    });



    //carrega modulos na variavel "app"
    consign({ cwd: 'app' }).include('routes').then('controllers').then('helpers').into(app);
    return app;
}
```

***Minha rota de imagem***

```
module.exports = function(app) {

    app.get('/imagem/:nome', function(request, response, next){
        var path = require("path");
        var nome_imagem = request.params.nome;
        response.sendFile(path.resolve('app', 'public', `${nome_imagem}`) );
    });


    app.post('/imagem', function(request, response, next){

        var file = request.files.img;
        var extensao = file.name.slice('.');
        var nome_arquivo = 'img-' + Date.now() + '.' + extensao;

        file.mv(`app/public/${nome_arquivo}`, function(err){
            if(err){
                return response.status(500).send(err);
            }
        })

    });


}
```

*Obs: estou usando o express: 4.16.4
     e a lib jsonwebtoken: 8.3.0*

Comment: Se não me engano o express permite passar expressões regulares, tente trocar `app.use(function(request, response, next){` por `app.get('/[^imagem]', function(request, response, next){` no middleware que valida o token. De uma olhada [nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/303909/) relacionada

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam não funcionou, continua não deixando passar a rota.

Comment: Não é melhor você isolar as rotas e colocar o `middleware` só nas que você quer?

Comment: @Sorack, sim para uma aplicação pequena é valido, porém com o crescimento da aplicação não ficaria viável sempre que fosse criada uma rota colocar o middleware.

Comment: Muda no seu `if` para as condições ficarem assim: `request.originalUrl.indexOf('/imagem') !== -1)`

Comment: @Sorack, vlw funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar expressão regular dentro do seu `middleware` para verificar se a `URL` é de um dos caminhos que você deseja evitar a validação.

```
const { originalUrl: url } = request;

if (/\/(imagem|token|login)(\/|$)/.test(url)) {
  return next();
}
```

A expressão demonstrada acima cobre os seguintes casos:

- www.xyz.com/imagem
- www.xyz.com/imagem/
- www.xyz.com/imagem/1
- www.xyz.com/login
- www.xyz.com/login/
- www.xyz.com/login/1
- www.xyz.com/token
- www.xyz.com/token/
- www.xyz.com/token/1